# R Text Mining and Random Forest

Tags: r, text-mining

I am working on a data set that has a bunch of raw text that I am vectorizing and using in my matrix for a random forest regression. My question is, should I be treating each word as a .factor or a .numeric if it is a sparse matrix? Which one speed up the computation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that R matrices coerce factors to characters, so you're better off using numeric.

I'm not terribly familiar with RandomForest -- I have a general idea of what it does, but I'm not sure about the guts of its R implementation. If you need to give it a design matrix (for instance, how ANOVAs or GLMs work when you implement them by hand), you can try using the `model.matrix` function.